# Getting 'Permission denied' error in Gitbash while using git init command

Tags: git

I have my script in eclipse IDE and which is being stored in my C disk as default.While using git init to initialize my local repository Getting 'Permission denied' error in Gitbash.

If i copy my code to some other folder and try the same git command, its working fine.

Could someone please help me out on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Permission Denied" generally means that your user does not have permission to modify or change things in that directory.  The reasons for that could by many, but it generally boils down to one of two: you're trying to do this on a system path not meant for users, or you did something as one user but are trying to do this step as a different user (who doesn't have the necessary permissions).  This isn't a Git problem, it's an operating system permissions/user issue.

Comment: My code is there in user path, C:\Users\MyProject\MavenProject is the path. if i need an access to this path to manipulate  this in git, how can i get it?

Comment: Could someone please guide me on above ask?

Comment: `C:\Users\MyProject` is outside of your user directory. Use your home directory instead. In git bash enter `cd $HOME` to get there

Comment: I have changed my eclipse storage location from user to someother location and now the error has gone.Thanks @Robert and John Szakmeister